# function inheritance doesn't work

Tags: solidity, remix, testrpc

Why does the attached contract always throw an invalid opcode when I execute `test()` and `verify()` (in that order)?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract Parent
{

    uint value;

    function isValueOne() public constant returns (bool) {
        return value == 1;
    }

}


contract Child is Parent
{

    uint public value;

    function test() public {
        value = 1;
    }

    function verify() {
        require(isValueOne());
    }
}
```

From my understanding, this should never be the case. I've read the docs on inheritance and I couldn't find out what's going on. After moving  `isValueOne` to `Child` everything works.

I've tested this code on testrpc and remix with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is failing for a few reasons.

1- Function verify() is not marked as constant. It should be marked as constant given that it is reading data and not writing. (Fixing this will eliminate the error you are getting).

2- Even when this error is fixed, the contract will not work as intended because you are declaring uint public value in the Child which shadows the declaration of the variable with the same name/type in Parent.

Here's how your code should look for it to work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract Parent
{

    uint public value;

    function isValueOne() public constant returns (bool) {
        return (value == 1);
    }

}


contract Child is Parent
{

    function test() public {
        value = 1;
    }

    function verify() constant returns (bool) {
        require(isValueOne());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and it works. I've read somewhere that `constant` doesn't do anything currently, what would cause this fail here? This should definitely be documented.

Comment: The compiler won't enforce adding it, but you do have to add it in order to tell it to use eth_call function instead of eth_sendTransaction.

Comment: Given that I change something in `verify()` and update a property, therefore removing `constant`, this code will fail. I don't think that's right

Comment: You are not currently modifying any state variable in verify().

Comment: For reference, the problem was that I redefined `value` in `Child`. The compiler should throw an error in this case, this issue is already opened on github https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2563  (I was able to find this after being reminded of shadowing.)